# Git clone - but keep remote upstream

Tags: git

My working flow like as

> git clone **ssh://github**  /work/local

> git clone  /work/local  /work/tmp

But I want to keep **/work/tmp** tacking to **ssh://github**.

I know options **--mirror** at first repo or manually **git remote add ...** on /work/tmp/ could achieve it.

But is any easier just some option of **git clone**?

Comment: Just copy the .git folder rather than cloning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Remember, though, that `git clone` is just a convenience single-line version of the following six commands:

1. `mkdir path` (if/as necessary): create new empty directory for new repository;
2. `git -C path init`: create new empty repository in empty directory specified in step 1;
3. `git -C path remote add remote url`: set up the URL; the *`remote`* is `origin` unless specified otherwise via `-o`;
4. additional `git config` operations (in the target path) as specified by any `git clone -c` options;
5. `git -C path fetch remote`: fetch commits from `origin` or specified remote name;
6. `git -C path switch branch`: create branch and populate working tree (suppressed with `-n`, modified slightly for tag based clones).

By running these commands yourself, you can choose how everything works out.  In particular, you can easily add a `git remote set-url` step *between* steps 5 and 6.